# date format in angular from json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, date

```
    .controller('feedCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('items.json').then(function(response) {
    $scope.items = response.data;
    $scope.user = localStorage.getItem("glittrLoggedin");

  });

}])



JSON file:

[
  {
    "_id": "55e76d010ea262760117d43c",
    "title": "sit",
    "picture": "https://placeimg.com/640/480/any",
    "company": {
      "title": "COMVEYOR",
      "email": "hello@gmail.com",
      "phone": "+1 (845) 472-3160"
    },
    "about": "Tempor aute incididunt commodo ad aute do sint laboris. Officia adipisicing enim adipisicing aliquip laborum amet dolore ullamco. Id sunt enim consectetur aute adipisicing ullamco ad non tempor commodo proident. Irure pariatur quis fugiat ad mollit minim commodo pariatur do velit excepteur laboris ipsum culpa. Ea ea exercitation nostrud laborum laborum quis nisi. Aliqua ipsum enim occaecat velit mollit commodo pariatur. Magna ea laboris est et elit quis excepteur incididunt aute anim pariatur dolore irure cupidatat.",
    "createdAt": "Wed Apr 30 2014 18:57:48 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
  },
  {
    "_id": "55e76d017700a7889c317092",
    "title": "in",
    "picture": "https://placeimg.com/640/480/any",
    "company": {
      "title": "RODEMCO",
      "email": "hello@gmail.com",
      "phone": "+1 (821) 468-2057"
    },
    "about": "Ea in minim cupidatat id reprehenderit. Ut voluptate do mollit sit ullamco aliquip. Esse dolore labore velit ullamco nostrud tempor sit exercitation aute consectetur excepteur dolore occaecat. Tempor elit incididunt laborum esse dolor magna.",
    "createdAt": "Tue Apr 29 2014 20:52:30 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
  }
]
```

I am trying to format the 'createdAT' in the format yyyy-MM-dd. I tried the following in my HTML but still get the code in the same format.

```
 {{item.createdAt | date :'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

Link to code: [plunkrlink](http://plnkr.co/edit/dh1gnqMpTx1uxHKBAGzu?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the string of date to `date` object to apply `date` filter  on it, for that you need to create a function inside your controller `convertToDate` that will provide you the date object, afterwards apply an filter on it.

**Markup**

```
<text fill="#ffffff" font-size="10" font-family="Verdana" x="20" y="66">
   {{convertToDate(item.createdAt)| date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
</text>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.convertToDate = function(date) {
    var dateOut = new Date(date);
    dateOut.setDate(new Date(date).getDate() + 1);
    return dateOut;
};
```

[**Working Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/iT3Pjm4r32P9gmk6eCFO?p=preview)